# Parsing Playa as a Plugin Parameter

Tags: parse-order

Trying to put the Playa children results into a parameter of a plugin to pass as metadata.  First tried this, but it passed the tag itself.

```
{exp:channel:entries}
    {matrix_field}
    {asset_field var_prefix="abc"}
        {exp:myplugin:plugin artist="{exp:playa:children backspace='2'}{title}, {/exp:playa:children}"}
        <audio src="{url}">
        {/exp:myplugin:plugin}
    {/asset_field}
    {/matrix_field}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

So tried the parse="inward" technique, but for each result/relationship it repeated the {url}:

```
{exp:channel:entries}
    {matrix_field}
    {asset_field var_prefix="abc"}
    {exp:playa:children backspace="2" parse="inward"}
            {exp:myplugin:plugin artist="{title}"}
            <audio src="{url}">
            {/exp:myplugin:plugin}
    {/exp:playa:children}
    {/asset_field}
    {/matrix_field}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

(added based on comment)  This returns blank for that parameter:

```
{exp:channel:entries}
    {matrix_field}
    {asset_field var_prefix="abc"}
        {exp:myplugin:plugin parse="inward" artist="{exp:playa:children backspace='2'}{title}, {/exp:playa:children}"}
        <audio src="{url}">
        {/exp:myplugin:plugin}
    {/asset_field}
    {/matrix_field}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

So how can the Playa tag be parsed before the plugin runs?  Stash or Low Variables approach?  I've never really used them so an example would be super helpful!

Comment: Try to put `parse="inward"` on your plugin tag

Comment: That's what I thought, and what makes sense, but its blank with parse='inwards' and passes the tag itself if left out.  Pulled the tag out of the plugin parameter, and worked, so I know it is correct.

Comment: Did you notice there's a " missing on your last code? `parse="inward` should be `parse="inward"`.

Comment: Ah thanks, probably a copy/paste/format typo.

Comment: ...And for the life of me I can't remember what this was for, so I'm not sure where to double-check if that was a typo or not in the template....